# Including function from "survival" in R package

Tags: r, dependencies, package, survival

I would like to include in my R package a new function, which requires the Surv function from the survival package.
I did include import(survival) in the NAMESPACE and I have survival installed; however, when I run R CMD check, I still get this error message:

Error in Surv(time, status) : could not find function "Surv"

I do have dependencies from other packages and I never faced such an issue. I already tried with no success to implement the solutions recommended here:

http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/requireNamespace-etiquette-td4703620.html

Any suggestions on what might be the problem?

Comment: It would be nice to have some sort of minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to test with.

Answer (score -1):

You have to do the following

1. `install.packages("survival")`
2. `library("survival")`

and then the `surv()` function will work